# Type safety: Unchecked cast in generic class

Tags: java, types, type-conversion, type-safety

I have a Generic class.It looks like this:

```
public class DataConverter<T> implements Converter<T> {

    @Override
public T convert(Class<T> type, Object value) {
    if ((type.equals(String.class)) && ... ) {
        return conevertDataToJSONString((Data) value);
    } 
    ...
}

    private T conevertDataToJSONString(Data data) {
        String value = gson.toJson(data);
        return (T) value; // << Type safety: Unchecked cast from String to T
    }
...
}
```

Obviously `conevertDataToJSONString` method only called when `T` be of String type.But there is a warning:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from String to T

Is there a way to solve that without using `SuppressWarnings`:

> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

before method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seemingly, you can use [`Class.cast(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) since you have the `Class<T>` already:

```
@Override
public T convert(Class<T> type, Object value) {
    if ((type.equals(String.class)) && ... ) {
        //     casting here
        return type.cast( conevertDataToJSONString((Data) value) );
    } 
    ...
}

// no need to make this method generic
private String conevertDataToJSONString(Data data) {
    return gson.toJson(data);
}
```

However, your use of `if(type.equals(String.class))` makes me wonder—because it means you have some foreknowledge of what `T` actually is. You should perhaps read [*"Why Use Generics?"*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) and consider whether generics are really the correct solution here.

Comment: finally a great answer, thanks! Much better than the "@SuppressLint" typical answer

Answer (score 0):

you must convert string to T by this code:

```java
String value = gson.toJson(data);
T elem = transformer.transform(value);
return T;
```